# Generating shapefile containing UTM grid (graticule)?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, utm, grids-graticules

I'm looking for a shapefile containing an 1000m or 2000m UTM grid ("graticule"). All I was about to find on the web is a 10000m UTM grid (here: http://en.giswiki.net/wiki/UTM) and I am aware that a 1000m UTM grid for the whole world might be quite big.

That's why I'm now wondering if and how it would be possible to generate such a shapefile for a part of the world. I would prefer to use open source tools like gdal. Others output formats than a shapefile might be ok too.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the other answers I was able to do it this way:

1. Determine the wanted UTM coordinates.

   - **UTM zone**: determine the zone between 1 and 60 by looking at a map like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system
   - **EPSG code for the UTM zone**: on WGS84 it is EPSG:326xx, where xx is the number of the zone (see http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/?page=18&search=UTM+zone).
     In Europe some maps use ETRS89 instead of WGS84. There is also a corresponding EPSG code (EPSG:258xx) but the difference to WGS84 is too small to notice, so that you can as well use WGS84.
   - **Easting**: within a zone the easting coordinate is always greater than 100000m and smaller than 900000m, so I simply take 100000-900000 as limits for the easting value.
   - **Northing**: it's the distance to the equator, let's say I need a 1000km part between 5000000m and 6000000m.
2. Use [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/) as suggested by johanvdw. Start a new project, select MODULES-SHAPES/TOOLS > CREATE GRATICULE, enter the following values and click “Okay”:[image]

   (*It might alternatively be possible to use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) as suggested by Darren Cope*)
3. Go to the tab “Data”, right click on the graticule in the tree and choose “Save as” to create a shapefile. Let's say “UTM_without_CS.shp”.
4. Use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to attribute a coordinate system. Let's say you want UTM zone 30 on WGS 84 (= EPSG:32630):

   ogr2ogr -a_srs EPSG:32630 UTM.shp  UTM_without_CS.shp

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this in [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org), A full explanation can be found here: http://marinedataliteracy.org/margis/grats_frames.htm

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard from SAGA GIS before. I have just made a quick try. I was at least able to generate a simple graticule. I haven't yet found if it is possible to select UTM coordinates, but I will try again another day. It seems promising.

Comment: Thanks again, it's working! I've simply generated a graticule with 1000m as distance on X and Y and export it as shapefile. Then I've assigned the coordinate system of the corresponding UTM zone to the shapefile using ogr2ogr (for example EPSG:32601 for zone 01 with WGS 84 as ellipsoid) and I have exactly what I need. I will try to make a step by step description later.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has a 'Vector Grid' tool (under Vector > Research Tools) that you can give extents and grid size. Sounds like it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. When I try it, QGIS freezes and I don't get anything. I might try again later if I have more chance.

Comment: Name; if are actually trying to generate a 1kmx1km grid for a large area, it's possible you are hitting the shapefile size limitation. Did you try a smaller area as a test? Also, make sure you have upgraded to the latest version of QGIS as well.

Comment: I tried with QGIS 1.6.0. I will download the current version 1.7.4 and try again. But in the window I could only enter the min and max value and no distance between the lines, so I doubt it will work for my purposes as I need 1000 or 2000m as grid distance.

Comment: It actually worked with version 1.7.4 by entering 1000 as parameter (But it's buggy because after entering 1000 it displayed a much bigger value). What surprised me it that the resulting shapefile is much smaller that with SAGA GIS (less than 500KB against 50MB for a 800x1000km area...)