# How to make polygon shapefile containing WGS 84 UTM zones as features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I need a shapefile with polygon features. Each feature has to be a unique UTM zone (each zone is 6 degrees) in the northern hemisphere.

I have no idea how to make it - **Create fishnet** gives a wrong result, and making it by hand is a time consuming operation.

How to automate this, or maybe download shapefile somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked at these questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7532/source-for-utm-zone-file Or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/how-to-generate-a-shapefile-containing-an-utm-grid-graticule

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Have found this: http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/world/utmzone.zip

Comment: I am very surprised to hear that Create Fishnet is giving a wrong result - I find it to be one of the most common and reliable tools that I use.

Comment: PolyGeo, as i understood, it gives parallel lines so when i need to make degree net it wont work (degree net is not parallel).

Comment: When you use a "geographic" coordinate system--its coordinates are in degrees of latitude and longitude--then indeed (most of) the UTM zone boundaries are regularly spaced. ("Parallel" is not a relevant concept here.) If you describe in more detail *how* you applied `Create fishnet`, perhaps someone will help you obtain the correct result with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArcGIS install should have a UTM Zones shapefile.
Have a look under **C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Reference Systems**

[image]