# Create an UTM/MGRS graticule/fishnet in Python

Tags: python, utm, mgrs

Following [Creating square grid polygon shapefile with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54119), I'd like to create an UTM or MGRS graticule in python. In the mentioned question the given answer gives me a way to generate a grid but I don't know if the SRS or the projection is wrong, but the grid is not aligned with the graticule available on [NGA](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/grids/mgrs_1km_polygon_dloads.html).

Here is what I get :

[image]

Red grid is the grid from NGA, it aligns well in regard with UTM zone 31 and distance is good too.
Blue grid is the one generated by the script I got from [Creating square grid polygon shapefile with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54119), but modified to take geographic bounds, and intended utm zone. There is a slight offset (better than previously)

```
import os, sys
import ogr
import osr
from math import ceil


def main(outputGridfn,lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax, utmZone, gridHeight,gridWidth):

   # create the spatial reference, WGS84
    targetSRS = osr.SpatialReference()


    targetSRS.SetProjCS( "UTM "+ utmZone+ " (WGS84) in northern hemisphere." );
    targetSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS( "WGS84" );
    targetSRS.SetUTM( int(utmZone), True );

    sourceSRS  = osr.SpatialReference()
    sourceSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

    poCT =osr.CoordinateTransformation ( sourceSRS, targetSRS )

    # convert sys.argv to float
    lonmin = float(lonmin)
    lonmax = float(lonmax)
    latmin = float(latmin)
    latmax = float(latmax)

    xmin,ymin,_ = poCT.TransformPoint(lonmin,latmin)
    print (xmin, ymin)
    xmax,ymax,_ = poCT.TransformPoint(lonmax,latmax)

    gridWidth = float(gridWidth)
    gridHeight = float(gridHeight)

    # get rows
    rows = ceil((ymax-ymin)/gridHeight)
    # get columns
    cols = ceil((xmax-xmin)/gridWidth)

    # start grid cell envelope
    ringXleftOrigin = xmin
    ringXrightOrigin = xmin + gridWidth
    ringYtopOrigin = ymax
    ringYbottomOrigin = ymax-gridHeight

    # create output file
    outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    if os.path.exists(outputGridfn):
        os.remove(outputGridfn)
    outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outputGridfn)


    outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer(outputGridfn,targetSRS,geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon )

    featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

    # create grid cells
    countcols = 0
    while countcols < cols:
        countcols += 1

        # reset envelope for rows
        ringYtop = ringYtopOrigin
        ringYbottom =ringYbottomOrigin
        countrows = 0

        while countrows < rows:
            countrows += 1
            ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
            ring.AddPoint(ringXleftOrigin, ringYtop)
            ring.AddPoint(ringXrightOrigin, ringYtop)
            ring.AddPoint(ringXrightOrigin, ringYbottom)
            ring.AddPoint(ringXleftOrigin, ringYbottom)
            ring.AddPoint(ringXleftOrigin, ringYtop)
            poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
            poly.AddGeometry(ring)

            # add new geom to layer
            outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
            outFeature.SetGeometry(poly)
            outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
            outFeature.Destroy

            # new envelope for next poly
            ringYtop = ringYtop - gridHeight
            ringYbottom = ringYbottom - gridHeight

        # new envelope for next poly
        ringXleftOrigin = ringXleftOrigin + gridWidth
        ringXrightOrigin = ringXrightOrigin + gridWidth

    # Close DataSources
    outDataSource.Destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #
    # example run : $ python grid.py <full-path><output-shapefile-name>.shp xmin xmax ymin ymax gridHeight gridWidth
    #

    if len( sys.argv ) != 9:
        print ("[ ERROR ] you must supply eight arguments: output-shapefile-name.shp lonmin lonmax latmin latmax utmZone gridHeight gridWidth")
        sys.exit( 1 )

    main( sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7],sys.argv[8] )
```

I'm quite confused at this time. Should I use directly UTM or MGRS coordinates?

I've seen in [Generating shapefile containing UTM grid (graticule)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26728) the option of using Saga GIS, but if possible I'd rather use code to be able to script it.

**Edit:** improved the computation

Comment: One issue could be how many vertices does your and/or the NGA grid have on each line. I personally would build the grid from XY coordinates not lat/lon ones.